# Проблема с повторным вызовом класса в Selenium

Tags: python, ооп, selenium, класс

Есть класс, который отвечает за ввод текста в поле. Текст указывается в самом тесте. При повторном вызове класса в одном тесте происходит ввод сразу старого и нового текста, например ТелефонСмартфон. Как сделать так, чтобы при повторном вызове класса не вводился старый текст?

- Класс Main_page

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

login = Login_page(driver)
login.authorisation()

mp = Main_page(driver)
mp.input_information("Сумка")
mp.click_list()

dp = Asd_page(driver)
dp.asd_getting()

np = Dvb_page(driver)
np.deposit_getting()


mp1 = Main_page(driver)
mp1.input_information("Товар")
mp1.click_list()
```

Пробовал применять `Keys.DELETE` после объявления класса

```
input_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "")
input_field.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
```

- Класс Main_Page

```
class Main_page(Base):


    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver

    # Locators

    input_field = ""
    list = ""

    # Getters

    def get_input_field(self):
        return WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.input_field)))
    
    def get_list(self):
        return WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.list)))
    

    
    # Actions

    def input_information(self, input_field):
        self.get_input_field().send_keys(input_field)
        print("Input information")

    def click_list(self):
        self.get_list().click()
        print("Click list")

    # Methods

    def input_info(self):
        self.get_current_url()
```

Comment: А где сам класс?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Добавил класс

Comment: Почему у вас поля `input_field` и `list` относятся к классу , а не к экземпляру класса?

Comment: Эти поля должны находиться в def __init__?